# The onFinish function of CountDownTimer is not executed inside an AccesibilityService until the user doesn't triger an event

Tags: android, service, accessibility, countdowntimer

I'm making an accesibility service in Android where i have a CountDownTimer, inside the onTick function i have a Log.d to know the time left of the timer. After 20 secons aproximatically it stops printing but the timer goes on. However when the timer ends the onFinish function is not trigered unless the user triggers any accesibility event.

Here is the funtion that starts the timer in Kotlin:

```
 private fun startTimer() {
        if (!isTimerRunning){
            Log.d("TIMER BLOCK", "TIMER STARTED")
            isTimerRunning = true
            timer = object : CountDownTimer(remainingTimeToday, 1000) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    remainingTimeToday = millisUntilFinished
                    Log.d("TIMER BLOCK", remainingTimeToday.toString())
                    // Update the remaining time in SharedPreferences
                    saveTimerData(false)
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    // Timer finished, handle the desired action
                    Log.d("TIMER BLOCK", "TIMER ON FINISH CALLED")
                    remainingTimeToday = 0L
                    checkTimeAndBlock()
                }
            }.start()
        }
    }
```

I have reed the AccesibilitySetting documentation and i couldn't find if it has something to do to Android applying restrictions to services uppon Android 8.0. The onFinish() function should be executed when the timer reaches 0, but it doesn't. Thanks for your help.